# Java - Spock "where" block is not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, spock, micronaut

I am trying to write some test with where but it seems like the data mentioned in where block is not being passed, (I found the values to be null).
Here is my unit test:

```
    def "method response should contain count as expected" () {
        given:
        SomeServiceImpl service = applicationContext.getBean(SomeServiceImpl.class)

        when:
        mockConnector.getResponse(userId) >> responseData
        service.setTokenConnector(mockConnector)
        ResponseData res = tokenService.getAllData(userId)
        def count = ((ListResponseMeta)(res.getMeta())).getCount()

        then:
        count == expected

        where:
        responseData | expected
        tokenInfos | 1
        null | 0
    }
```

The `tokenInfos` is initialized previously as an array of object with some values.

```
    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    Info[] tokenInfos = null

    def setup() {
        tokenInfos = getMockInfoBody()
        mockTokenConnector = Mock(SampleConnector.class)
    }

    private static Info[] getMockInfoBody() {
        Info infoDeactivated = new Info("123", "http://abc.xyz.com", "D")
        Info infoActive = new Info("234", "http://abc.xyz.com", "A")
        Info infoSuspended = new Info("235", "http://abc.xyz.com", "S")

        Info[] tokenInfos = new Info[3]
        tokenInfos[0] = infoDeactivated
        tokenInfos[1] = infoActive
        tokenInfos[2] = infoSuspended

        return tokenInfos
    }
```

I tried moving responseData within `when` block previously `responseData` was being used in `given` block. Please help here.

Comment: please add the complete source code for this test class. otherwise its hard to tell what might be wrong

Comment: Try moving the stub (`mockConnector.getResponse(userId) >> responseData`) and other setup (`service.setTokenConnector(mockConnector)`) into the `given` block. Normally don't see the stub in the when block.

Comment: _"`tokenInfos` is initialized previously as an array of object with some values"_ - Initialised how? Which values? What is unexpectedly null during the test? Is this some kind of game show where you are hiding the very thing you are asking about to make it harder for the candidates to answer correctly? Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: @ShingJo I already tried it before, but that didn't help

Comment: @kriegaex I added the initialization

Comment: @suvodipMondal, thanks for doing that. You did yourself the biggest favour by following my advice, because it enabled Leonard to answer your question, even though it was not really an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) even after your edit. See, that is the beauty of this community: You are not dependent on a single person. Yesterday, I did not check in here anymore, and in the meantime another community member has stepped in and answered your question. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer, but as @krigaex pointed out, without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to be sure.

There are multiple things that are wrong or have no effect.

1. `@AutoCleanup` will call the `close()` method on the field's object. Here, the field is an array, which doesn't have a `close()` method.
2. You declare `tokenInfos` to be `@Shared`, but you only initialize it in the first `setup()` call, which will happen too late for the first entry in the `where` block. So, either initialze the field directly, or move the assignment to `setupSpec`.

```
    @Shared
    Info[] tokenInfos = getMockInfoBody()
    // OR
    def setupSpec() {
        tokenInfos = getMockInfoBody()
    }
```

Currently, you were method basically looks like this

```
        where:
        responseData | expected
        null         | 1        // tokenInfos is still null as setup() didn't run yet
        null         | 0
```

Comment: Got it, intializing in `setupSpec` method works